# mysql insert autoincrement mul key

Tags: mysql

all,

Suppose I have the following mysql table `testtable`:

```
+----------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| testID   | bigint(12) unsigned zerofill | NO   | MUL | NULL    | auto_increment |
| testcol  | varchar(10)                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| testcol1 | varchar(10)                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| testcol2 | varchar(10)                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| testcol3 | varchar(10)                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| testcol4 | varchar(10)                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I then insert several rows by running, let's say 5 times:

`INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (null, 'testcol', 'testcol1', 'testcol2', 'testcol3', 'testcol4');`

Then delete one row with `testID = 000000000002`:

`DELETE FROM testtable WHERE testID = 000000000002;`

**My question is:**

Will testID be reassigned as `000000000002` again later by running the same insert statement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you don't specify the key, the engine assign a new autoincremented value. You can assign the 0000000002 key with an explicit insert

```
INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (0000000002, 'testcol', 'testcol1', 'testcol2', 'testcol3', 'testcol4');
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't want to do explicit insert. I am facing an issue the `testID` is reassigned and trying to figure out why.